# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup: find the text outside of a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to play with BeautifulSoup by returning the book titles of a certain search result of genlib:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=physics&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for html in soup.find_all('tr', {'valign': 'top', 'bgcolor':'#C6DEFF'}):
    print(html.find('a', {'href': re.compile("book/index.php\?md5=.")}).text)
```

The relevant HTML:

```
<a href="book/index.php?md5=AAC0058748685BAEB782D1A156A2ED25" id="28" title="">
 Physics of life
 <br/>
 <font color="green" face="Times">
  <i>
   0444527982, 9780444527981, 9780080554648
  </i>
 </font>
</a>
<a href="book/index.php?md5=C892C74AEAC46715475EF5334302D751" id="48" title="">
 Physics and Chemistry Basis of Biotechnology
 <br/>
 <font color="green" face="Times">
  <i>
   9780306468919, 0306468913
  </i>
 </font>
</a>
```

Everything worked fine, except the outputs include the some unwanted ISBN codes:

```
"""
Physics of life 0444527982, 9780444527981, 9780080554648

Physics and Chemistry Basis of Biotechnology 9780306468919, 0306468913

Lectures On Statistical Physics And Protein Folding [illustrated edition] 9812561439, 9789812561435, 9789812569387, 9812561501
...
"""
```

I want to get rid of the numbers, however both the book titles and the numbers are inside the `<a></a>` tags, and the numbers are further inside the `<i></i>` tags. It appeared to me instantly that I can extract the ISBN by putting ".i.text" at the end, but how can I extract the book titles only?

Comment: It's no doubt horrible non-robust, but you might be able to do `.next.text` instead of `.text`... to get the immediately following item after the anchor...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an elegant way to extract the book title with beautifulsoup.

An easy work around though would be to extract the ISBN and then use the replace function to replace the ISBN with an empty string. Then clean up any whitespace with with strip function.

```
titleString.replace(isbnString, "").strip()
```

Replace:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Strip:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
for html in soup.find_all('tr', {'valign': 'top', 'bgcolor':'#C6DEFF'}):
    print(html.find('a', {'href': re.compile("book/index.php\?md5=.")}).next)
```

The next returns the next tag text in the soup.

Answer (score 0):

## use find_next

```
for html in soup.find_all('tr', {'valign': 'top', 'bgcolor':'#C6DEFF'}):
    print(html.find('a', {'href': re.compile("book/index.php\?md5=.")}).find_next(text = True))
```